# Having issues with React Router endpoints

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, endpoint

So I am currently doing a Web Dev boot camp, and we are busy with a project where we make an API for an application where you can browse movies, select your favourite, make a profile etc.

The current task, has us implementing React Routers to the endpoints.
I followed the code as per the exercise but my app would only show my navbar and background colour. I went into the dev tools, and got this error.

```
utils.ts:767 Matched leaf route at location "/register" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.
OR
Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.
```

I looked online for answers, but every answer refers to changing "component" to "element". The problem is, the code that we were taught, doesn't even have that included.

Just some of the code:

```
render() {
    const { movies, user, favouriteMovies } = this.state;
    console.log(favouriteMovies);
    return (
      <Router>
        <NavBar user={user} />
        <Row className="main-view justify-content-md-center">
         <Routes>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/" 
            render={() => {
              /* If there is no user, the LoginView is rendered. If there is a user logged in, 
       the user details are passed as a prop to the LoginView */
              if (!user)
                return (
                  <Col>
                    <LoginView
                      movies={movies}
                      onLoggedIn={(user) => this.onLoggedIn(user)}
                    />
                  </Col>
                );
              // Before the movies have been loaded
              if (movies.length === 0) return <div className="main-view" />;

              return movies.map((m) => (
                <Col md={6} lg={3} key={m._id} className="movie-card">
                  <MovieCard movie={m} />
                </Col>
              ));
            }}
          />
          <Route
            path="/register"
            render={() => {
              if (user) return <Redirect to="/" />;
              return (
                <Col>
                  <RegistrationView />
                </Col>
              );
            }}
          />
```

I then asked on Slack where the other students chat. There was someone with the same issue and they said they installed an older version and it worked.

```
npm install react-router-dom@5.3.0
```

I did that, but now my navbar doesn't show, only the background colour.
I also have a different error.

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:86
main-view.jsx:125 Array(0)
react-jsx-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `MainView`.
    at MainView (http://localhost:1234/index.6701a6e1.js:25282:9)
    at MyFlixApplication (http://localhost:1234/index.6701a6e1.js:955:1)
printWarning @ react-jsx-runtime.development.js:87
react-dom.development.js:28439 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `MainView`.
    at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (react-dom.development.js:28439:17)
    at createFiberFromElement (react-dom.development.js:28465:15)
    at reconcileSingleElement (react-dom.development.js:15750:23)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:15808:35)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:19167:28)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:19924:3)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21618:14)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <div> component:

    at div
    at http://localhost:1234/index.6701a6e1.js:43098:48
    at Router2 (http://localhost:1234/index.6701a6e1.js:29157:34)
    at BrowserRouter2 (http://localhost:1234/index.6701a6e1.js:28837:39)
    at MainView (http://localhost:1234/index.6701a6e1.js:25282:9)
    at MyFlixApplication (http://localhost:1234/index.6701a6e1.js:955:1)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

My tutor isn't able to find what the problem is.

I have really been struggling with this and would really appreciate any assistance.

The link to my repo:
https://github.com/Claudiaj501/myFlix-client/tree/Router

Answer (score 0):

React Router v6 makes heavy use of React hooks, so you'll need to be on React 16.8+. [The React Router Docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5) and [Upgrade Guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5) will show you the differences between the two. Changing "component" to "element" is one of the several differences between the two versions. [Here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) are the docs for the version 5 of React Router.

In your warning it tell you "ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18". You should be using React functional components and not classes with the latest version of react.

In order to use v6, you'll need to convert all your Switch elements to Routes. So if you downgraded from 6 to 5, you can't use Routes.

Here is a v5 example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/users">
      <Users />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And here is the same example in v6:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="users/*" element={<Users />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

You need to decide what version of everything you are using and stick to that. Several packages have major differences between versions. And you need to make sure that the version you are using of package X is compatible with React version Y.